# Use parent events on custom Button class

Tags: powershell, oop, events

i want to create a GUI with clickable buttons. I've started it in procedural, but i want to continue in object. So i restarted my project.
Now, i'm a bit stuck with Events, especially Add_Click.

Here is my custom button class

```
class ConfigButton : Windows.Forms.Button {

    # Constructor

    ConfigButton ([String]$Label, [int] $PosX, [int] $PosY) {       
        # Set properties
        $this.Text = $Label
        $this.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($PosX,$PosY)
        $this.Autosize = $True
    }

    # Functions

    [void] AddToWindow([ConfigWindow]$Window) {
        $Window.Controls.Add($this)
    }

    [String] ToString() {
        return $this.Text
    }

    #Events
}
```

**My question is : how to add the Add_Click event in my custom class ?**
I've tried naively with `$this.Add_Click`, but nope.

Here is my "Main", where i create my object and add it to my main window (raw values are here for test purpose)

```
$Main = New-Object ConfigWindow("Main Window", 1000, 800)

$ButtonClose = New-Object ConfigButton("Fermer",200, 200)

$ButtonClose.AddToWindow($Main)

Write-Host $ButtonClose.ToString()

$Main.DisplayWindow()
```

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to add it - it's already there, inherited from `Button` :) Just do `$ButtonClose.add_Click({ <# click handler action goes here #> })`

Comment: Tha'ts what i've finally did. Not what i wanted to do, but it seems i don't have any other choice.